# Gatsby: How do you get ACF (Advanced Custom Fields) to work with "gatsby-source-wordpress" plugin?

Tags: wordpress, gatsby, advanced-custom-fields

I tried following along to this tutorial but it is using a much older version of the API than the current version so it didn't work:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8PAV_9JKW48

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, so apparently you need the [WPGraphQL for Advanced Custom Fields](https://www.wpgraphql.com/acf/) plugin for it to work.

Download the latest version as a zip from [the GitHub releases page](https://github.com/wp-graphql/wp-graphql-acf/releases), then install it into your WordPress instance by uploading the zip folder (Plugins > add new > Upload Plugin).

Make sure that the **"show in GraphQL"** checkbox is checked on any advanced custom fields that you make or they won't appear in the GraphQL output.

These are all the WordPress plugins that you need to make everything run smoothly:

- [Advanced Custom Fields](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/)
- [WP Gatsby](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-gatsby/)
- [WP GraphiQL](https://github.com/wp-graphql/wp-graphiql/releases)
- [WP GraphQL](https://github.com/wp-graphql/wp-graphql/releases)
- [WPGraphQL for Advanced Custom Fields](https://github.com/wp-graphql/wp-graphql-acf/releases)

Restart Gatsby once everything is installed.

Comment: Working perfectly for me, thanks! As an additional note, don't forget to go to check `Show in GraphQL` at the very bottom of the ACF page when editing your custom fields.

Comment: Thanks, I've added mention of the "show in GraphQL" checkbox to the answer now.